# Combining two Directive0 with &

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have predefined two Directive0 as below:

```
def mySetCookie = if(cookies.length == 1) setCookie(cookies(0)) else if(cookies.length > 1) setCookie(cookies(0), cookies.tail: _*) else pass
def mySetHeader = if(headers.length > 0) respondWithHeaders(headers: _*) else pass
```

While trying to use these two directives together, the following works:

```
mySetCookie
{
  mySetHeader
  {
    complete(StatusCodes.OK)
  }
}
```

but the following doesn't:

```
mySetCookie & mySetHeader
{
  complete(StatusCodes.OK)
}
```

I get the following message:

```
Error:(116, 21) type mismatch;
found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
(which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.ConjunctionMagnet[Unit]
```

I understand the error message, but is there a way by which I can combine the two directives like what I want to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing them in parentheses: `(mySetCookie & mySetHeader)` ?

Comment: Indeed - missed that - that works. Wish you could put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directives generally need to be enclosed in parentheses, like nicodp suggests. Try `(mySetCookies & mySetHeader)`